# Signalr as WCF Service for various clients

Tags: wcf, signalr

Need an advise on following.

What is the best option to host Signalr, could it be hosted as a WCF service?
This SignalR will be consumed by clients like web application (MVC4) and ios applications.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is No as far as I know. You cannot host SignalR hubs as a WCF service. As alternative to hosting in a ASP.NET website, you can choose self hosting approach as explained [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Self-host).

On the other hand, SignalR has client APIs for both ASP.NET and [iOS/OSX](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC). The easiest solution (and my recommendation) would be direct hub usage via the client API.

If you insist on to open a WCF endpoint to manage SignalR hubs, you can reach SignalR [IHubContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.ihubcontext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from WCF by using `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<YourHub>()`.

Only requirement here is that your WCF service must be hosted on the same web application with your SignalR hub. External WCF services from different service applications cannot reach your hubcontext.